# Googled but could not found solution for Bidirectional mapping with annotation in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have googled for this solution, but i could not found the solution with annotations. Let me explain the problem.
    I have 3 Entities(Profile, Message, Comment). I have imposed mapping among three entities.

```
One Profile can post N Messages
One Message can post by Profile and has N comments
Many Comment can post by One Profile and identified by One Message

@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
public class ProfileEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "profile_id")
    private long profileId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "profiles")
    private List<CommentEntity> comments;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "profiles")
    private List<MessageEntity> messages;

    public long getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }

    public void setProfileId(long profileId) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public List<CommentEntity> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(List<CommentEntity> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public List<MessageEntity> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(List<MessageEntity> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class MessageEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "message_id")
    private long messageId;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private String ceatedOn;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
    private ProfileEntity profiles;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "messages")
    private Set<CommentEntity> comments;

    @Transient
    private List<Link> linkList = new ArrayList<Link>();

    public long getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
    }

    public void setMessageId(long messageId) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getCeatedOn() {
        return ceatedOn;
    }

    public void setCeatedOn(String ceatedOn) {
        this.ceatedOn = ceatedOn;
    }

    public ProfileEntity getProfiles() {
        return profiles;
    }

    public void setProfiles(ProfileEntity profiles) {
        this.profiles = profiles;
    }

    public Set<CommentEntity> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(Set<CommentEntity> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public List<Link> getLinkList() {
        return linkList;
    }

    public void setLinkList(List<Link> linkList) {
        this.linkList = linkList;
    }

    public void addLink(String link, String rel) {
        Link lnk = new Link();
        lnk.setLink(link);
        lnk.setRel(rel);
        linkList.add(lnk);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class CommentEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "comment_id")
    private long commentId;

    @Column(name = "comment")
    private String comment;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
    private ProfileEntity profiles;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "message_id")
    private MessageEntity messages;

    public long getCommentId() {
        return commentId;
    }

    public void setCommentId(long commentId) {
        this.commentId = commentId;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public ProfileEntity getProfiles() {
        return profiles;
    }

    public void setProfiles(ProfileEntity profiles) {
        this.profiles = profiles;
    }

    public MessageEntity getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    public void setMessages(MessageEntity messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
    }
}
```

Problem:

I am able select or delete Profile, but when i try to select messages, It is not rendering on the ReST client. I am doubting that it leads to circular mapping. can any body help me in this

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a EAGER fetch. When you have :

```
    @OneToMany
```

Replace it adding

```
    @OneToMany (fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
```

It will automatically populate your list when you call your object .

If you want some details about it check this link : https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-eager-vs-lazy-fetch-type/

Comment: I have tried with EAGER fetch also. it did't work. I did not get any errors, but as per my analysis it is going into circular mapping state.

Comment: Remove all eager fetch on @ManyToOne annotation

Answer (score 0):

This may be a circular mapping state exactly for this reason: because you have declared `FetchType.EAGER` in the relationships of `CommentEntity` and `MessageEntity`.

Circular mapping state can be eliminated if you declare for all of them `FetchType.LAZY`.

By the way, a stacktrace and/or a reported error message would help more.